# Debug highlighting missing in VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Somehow, after a vscode update my debug line-highlighting line is gone. Debugging works normal, but I never see the correct debugging line. The grey highliting in the screen below is just the cursor-line highlighting.

In the picture below, current debug position is line 147 - but no yellow debug line.

When i press F5, the next line gets highlighted grey, because the cursor switches there. But still no yellow highlight for my currently debuged line. When i click on on another line in the code the grey line switches to that position, leaving the current debug line without any highlighting.

I have a skin installed, "Solarized Express Soda", but deactivation does not fix this.

Is it possible to switch vscode versions back to test this further? Or to deactivate all extentions at once to have a vanilla vscode to approach the problem via elimination process?

VScode Version 1.46.1,
Node Version 10.21.0

[image: Missing Highlight]

Comment: I have seen the same behavior on the same release. However, it is erratic. I have one specific file that it refuses to highlight. But the other files highlight the current line just fine. Not sure if it makes any difference but these are mjs files on an Express server. When I rename that file as JS, though, it makes no difference.

Comment: I experienced that issue in correlation with asynchronous operations and Async/Await - i am pretty shure only those Promis-Based functions suffer on this issue. - so far my observations on that. Bottom line: I am stuck on VSCode January, where the issue is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, i solved the problem now.

I installed a previous version of vscode, january 1.42.1 - Now it works again properly. I think i will report this issue on the vscode forums.  Pherhaps an issue in correlation with my many extentions & old node version 10.21.0(which is still in need - thats another topic)

But perhaps, someone can tell me what I've done wrong, actually, i cant see anything wrong on my side here...

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue.